# many sign for a transaction

Tags: cleos

`cleos push action test do '["test","test2","100.0000 SYS"]' -p test@active test2@active`

I get an error:

```
Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"test2","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms
```

Comment: Do you have the key pair for test2 in your wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you can write many permissions after the -p option.

Only one permission is available as below.

**cleos push action -h**

-p, - permission TEXT ... An account and permission level to authorize, as in 'account @ permission'